# Password works uppercase/lowercase

Tags: ubuntu

Why does my password work both in UPPERCASE and lowecase when logging in on the console?

```
$ uname -a
4.15.0-48-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 3 08:28:49 UTC 2019 x86\_64 x86\_64 x86\_64 GNU/Linux
```

Ubuntu 18.04 with latest official updates

Comment: Do you mean logging in via the Console or via SSH ?